# parseInt() and parseFloat(): Can this second assertion ever fail?

Tags: javascript, parseint, proof, parsefloat

I've been using `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` in various contexts for a while now, and I'd like to think I know all the ins and outs of the two. But recently I had a curious thought which I so far haven't been able to definitively work out a proof for.

Consider the following function:

```
function testProof(strInteger) {
    assert(strInteger === '' + parseInt(strInteger, 10));

    assert(parseInt(strInteger, 10) === parseFloat(strInteger));
}

// Sample calls...
testProof("5");
testProof("109");
testProof("-55");
```

First we `assert` that converting the input to an integer and then converting back to a string produces the original string again. This guards against cases where `parseInt("100bucks")` returns `100`, and it also makes sure there is no fractional part that's getting truncated off by the conversion -- we want to make sure that the input is actually a whole number, integer string.

If that succeeds, we then `assert` that `parseInt(..., 10)` returns the same value as `parseFloat(...)`.

There are many reasons why the first `assert` would fail:

- Input is not a whole number (`"1.5"`)
- Input has leading zeros (`"0050"`)
- Input has trailing garbage (`"100bucks"`)
- Input is in exponential notation (`"1e3"`), or it's so large it becomes exponential
- Input is not parseable, resulting in `NaN`
- Maybe others?

**But here's the question:** As long as the first `assert` passes, can the second `assert` ever fail? Put another way, if we know ahead of time that the input is an integer inside a string, can `parseFloat(...)` function as a drop-in replacement for `parseInt(..., 10)`? (Not saying it's a *good* replacement... :-P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually can fail only with this input:

```
testProof("NaN");
```

But if you really know it's an integer, why the test? Also parseFloat can't be a good replacement for parseInt as in lots of cases you don't know if it's really an integer and not a float.

Comment: Good catch! I never considered trying a literal `"NaN"`. And I agree, this is probably something that shouldn't be done; it's more of a theoretical curiosity seeing if there are edge cases where the two act differently.

Comment: @smitelli Well, they behave differently only when you don't know what's inside of the string. And on the other hand if you are pretty sure it's a stringified integer, it's much easier to just do `+str` or `str * 1`.

Answer (score -1):

While I cannot offer a proof, JS has no distinction between an integer and a float.  The only difference between parseFloat and parseInt is how they interpret things like decimal points.  If the input string is a valid integer in regular notation, though (as the first assertion asserts), they will always result in the same numeric value, which in JS means they are the same type as well.